# how can i access to Array of function in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

i am new in swift.
i have make a collectionview in nib file and i have a subview of that in main view controller.
i want show array in collectionview but i could not.
first i make a model of day:

```
struct Days {    
    let day: String
    let Image: String
    let temp: Double
}
```

then in daycell:

```
class DayCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var lblDay: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var imgWeather: KBImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblTemp: UILabel!    
    func updateViews(day: Days) {
        lblDay.text = day.day
        imgWeather.setImageWithKingFisher(url: day.Image)
        lblTemp.text = String(day.temp)
    }
}
```

then in public class, i get json data with alamofire and decode that and put them in my model:

```
public class Publics {
    static let instance = Publics()  

func showInfo(code: String, completion: @escaping ([Days]) -> Void)  {


    let DaysUrl = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=\(code)&appid=3e28385cde03f6ee26c83b629ca274cc"
       Alamofire.request(DaysUrl, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody).responseJSON { response in
            if let data = response.data {
                do {
                    self.myJson = try JSONDecoder().decode(JsonForecast.Response.self, from: data)                   

                    let counter = (self.myJson?.list.count)! - 1

                    let myDay1 = self.myJson?.list[counter-32]
                    let myDay2 = self.myJson?.list[counter-24]
                    let myDay3 = self.myJson?.list[counter-16]                   

                    let weekDay1 = self.getDate(date: self.getDayOfWeek((myDay1?.dt_txt)!)!)
                    let weekDay2 = self.getDate(date: self.getDayOfWeek((myDay2?.dt_txt)!)!)
                    let weekDay3 = self.getDate(date: self.getDayOfWeek((myDay3?.dt_txt)!)!)

                   let DaysArray = [
                        Days(day: weekDay1, Image: (myDay1?.weather[0].icon)!, temp: (myDay1?.main?.temp)!) ,
                        Days(day: weekDay2, Image: (myDay2?.weather[0].icon)!, temp: (myDay2?.main?.temp)!) ,
                        Days(day: weekDay3, Image: (myDay3?.weather[0].icon)!, temp: (myDay3?.main?.temp)!)
                    ]
                    completion(DaysArray)
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

till here i do not have problem but now i want to show DaysArray in collectionview but i can not and my collectionview class is below:

```
class DayCollection: UIView, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    @IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionDay: UICollectionView!
    var days = [Days]()


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "DayCell", for: indexPath) as! DayCell

        Publics.instance.showInfo(code: "112931") { result in
            self.days = result
            print(self.days)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.collectionDay.reloadData()
            }
        }
        let day = days[indexPath.item]
        cell.updateViews(day: day)

            return cell

    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return days.count
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        self.collectionDay.dataSource = self
        self.collectionDay.delegate = self
        self.collectionDay.register(UINib(nibName: "DayCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "DayCell")

    }
}
```

what should i do in mainVC class?
(maybe i should i use from protocol delegate or no?)

Comment: You need a completion handler in the api request function, https://medium.com/@nimjea/completion-handler-in-swift-4-2-671f12d33178

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all if you want to have **constants** in a struct declare them as **constants**. `private(set)` is horrible.

```
struct Days {    
    let day: String
    let dImage: String
    let temp: Double 
}
```

And **never ever** declare struct members as implicit unwrapped optionals which are initialized with non-optional values in an `init` method. The init method in a struct is not needed anyway.

---

You have to add a completion handler

```
public func showInfo(code: String, completion: @escaping ([Days]) -> Void)  {

...

let daysArray = [
   Days(day: weekDay1, Image: (myDay1?.weather[0].icon)!, temp: (myDay1?.main?.temp)!) ,
   Days(day: weekDay2, Image: (myDay2?.weather[0].icon)!, temp: (myDay2?.main?.temp)!) ,
   Days(day: weekDay3, Image: (myDay3?.weather[0].icon)!, temp: (myDay3?.main?.temp)!)
]
completion(daysArray)
}
```

Then in the class of the collection view add a data source array

```
var days = [Days]()
```

and get the data

```
Publics.instance.showInfo(code: "Foo") { result in
   self.days = result
   DispatchQueue.main.async {
       self.collectionDay.reloadData()
    }
}
```

and `return days.count` in `numberOfItemsInSection`

Further force unwrap the cell

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "DayCell", for: indexPath) as! DayCell
```

If the code crashes you made a design mistake. With the optional binding the code doesn't crash but you don't see anything and you don't know why

and get a day

```
let day = days[indexPath.item]
cell.updateViews(day)
```

Comment: thank you from your perfect answer, but i have little problem. i made my collection in nib file and its class is ui view. i did your answer but i did not get answer. i update my post with your guide. but nothing show. please help me what should i do in main viewcontroller?      #vadian

Comment: and why private(set) is horrible and when should i use from that?

Comment: No, no, you have to put the code to receive the data into `viewDidLoad`. In `cellForItem` put only the lines to dequeue the cell, get the day from the data source array and configure the cell

Comment: `private(set)` smells *objective-c-ish* and is pretty cumbersome in terms of Swift. In Objective-C there are no constants.